# Pass a data(integer,string etc) from an activity in custom view to draw on canvas

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, android-activity

I have 3 activities in the application.

- First one - MainActivity contains just a button which takes to the SecondActivity.
- SecondActivity contains input text buttons in which I would enter the coordinates and a button which calls a ThirdAactivity which then sets CustomView on screen and canvas to draw.

  I need to pass the input taken from user in SecondActivity to the CustomView and then draw a line with that coordinates on canvas.

Please help.
I am a beginner at the android studio.

I am still getting some errors. Here's my code.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Button button;
// public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = 
"com.example.hrishi.newapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String Source= "com.example.hrishi.newapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String Destination = "com.example.hrishi.newapp.MESSAGE";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    final Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
     //Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
  //  final Intent intent = getIntent();
   // String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent Intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            EditText ent_source = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Source);
            EditText ent_dest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Dest);
            String source=ent_source.getText().toString();
            String dest=ent_dest.getText().toString();
            bundle.putInt("Source1", Integer.parseInt(source));
            bundle.putInt("Dest1", Integer.parseInt(dest));
            Intent.putExtras(bundle);
            //Intent.putExtra(Source,source);
            //Intent.putExtra(Destination,dest);


            startActivity(Intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Main Activity 3 Code:

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String source = intent.getStringExtra(Main2Activity.Source);
    //String dest = intent.getStringExtra(Main2Activity.Destination);
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    int Source1=bundle.getInt("Source1");
    int Dest1=bundle.getInt("Dest1");

   CustomView.setCoordinates(Source1,Dest1);

    setContentView(new com.example.hrishi.newapp.CustomView(this));

} }
```

My CustomView Code :

```
public class CustomView extends View {

draw a line here with those two coordinates

}
```

Comment: You can use `intent.putExtra()` method

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Bundle` to send data from one activity to another

In `SecondActivity`

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("KEYONE", valueCoordinateX);
bundle.putInt("KEYTWO", valueCoordinateY);
//Add the bundle to the intent
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

In `ThirdActivity`

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
//get the data from bundle
int valueCoordinateX= bundle.getInt("KEYONE");
int valueCoordinateY= bundle.getInt("KEYTWO");
```

//say your `CustomView` instance is `customView`

now `setCoordinates` to `customView`

```
CustomView customView = new CustomView(this)
customView.setCoordinates(valueCoordinateX,valueCoordinateY)
setContentView(customView)
```

where your CustomView class has a method `public void setCoordinates(int x,int y)`

```
public void setCoordinates(int x,int y){
this.globalX = x;
this.globalY = y;
//use globalX and globalY in `onDraw()` method
invalidate()
}
```

Comment: I have added the code to the Question.
I am still not getting it. Please help.
Also please review the code and suggest any changes to improve.

Comment: In your code what is this  - CustomView.setCoordinates(Source1,Dest1); and again what is this setContentView(new com.example.hrishi.newapp.CustomView(this)); is setCoordinates a static method. and you are adding new CustomView. what is happening here

Comment: Actually, we referred the Question asked previously on the same topic.
Here's the link
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188360/passing-a-variable-to-a-custom-view-class-from-actvity

We tried to implement the solution given in it. Hence the setCorodinnates statement is written.
Also setContentView(new com.example.hrishi.newapp.CustomView(this));  is setting the custom view on the screen.(CustomView was renamed, hence this statement pooped up the auto-complete.)

Comment: Did you implement successfully ?If yes, what was the problem with that implementation?

Comment: No. We couldn't. We can't figure out where to exactly write the given statements .

Comment: You are setting setContentView() as new View (new com.example.hrishi.newapp.CustomView(this)) , which will create a new view, it doesnot have any updated values

Comment: See updated answer @VeerBhansari

Comment: Now the application goes into the loop. After clicking the button on second activity, it redirects to first activity again without any canvas.
And yes we have a separate class called CustomView? I didnt get the CustomView instance part.4

Comment: Any Error StackTrace? First check till setCoordinates method ,are you getting any data(in logs) without drawing anything on Screen

Comment: No error in StackTrace. Where do I find logs for data?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html